# Strange C# error while inserting in database

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have 2 forms in my program. I am using a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database file (`.sdf`) from C#

`albums_tbl` table has two columns: `id`, `name`

In form 1 when I use this code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO albums_tbl(album_name) VALUES (@album_name) ", cn);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@album_name", textBox1.Text);

    int affectedrows = cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (affectedrows > 0)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("insert shod !");
    }
}
```

the program inserts well, but when I use the exact code in form 2 it errors this when I want to insert :

[image]

Comment: The error is not strange at all, you haven't open the connection.

Comment: Before executing the query, simply do `cn.Open();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't open connection yet.

```
SqlCeConnection conn = null;

try
{
    conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = MyDatabase.sdf; Password ='<pwd>'");
    conn.Open();

    SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers ([Customer ID], [Company Name]) Values('NWIND', 'Northwind Traders')";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection(v=vs.100).aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have not opened a connection , you just simply need to do as follow

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCeConnection con=new SqlCnConnection("Data Source = MyDatabase.sdf; Password ='<pwd>'");
    SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO albums_tbl(album_name) VALUES (@album_name) ", cn);
    cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter(@album_name, textBox1.Text));
    con.Open();
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```